# Could not establish Memcached connection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to create a connection from my PHP application to Memcache, however I keep getting the error 'Could not establish Memcached connection'.

Here's my package version information

```
Laravel Version: 5.0.32
PHP Version:5.4.39-0+deb7u2
Database Driver & Version:mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.31
Server&Version :Debian:7.1.
-memcached:1.4.13-0.2
-php5-memcached:2.0.1-6
```

I have ensured that memcached is running, as executing `service memcached status` yields "memcached is running".

I have two servers where my project is deployed:

- ubuntu, with memcached:2.1.0 installed
- debian, with memcached:2.0.1 installed

Is there a version conflict?

Comment: Did you check to ensure memcached is running? Are you connecting to the right port?

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clearer, and fix formatting. Feel free to edit if I've misrepresented your intent.

Comment: @Tyzoid,thanks for your answer~ I'm sure memcached service is running.In addition to check service status by command, this error which showing 'Could not establish Memcached connection' message occurs not always but frequently.If I run getversion to get memcached connection info , it works

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by myself.
My solution as follow:
1.delete memcache file and apc file in config dir
2.restart php5-fpm and memcached service.
Although issue is fixed, but I'm still not figure out why it was triggered.
This issue only occurs on the server with Debian os installed rather than the other server which with ubuntu os installed.
Hope help somebody~

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem with 
`sudo apt-get install memcached 
sudo service memcached status
sudo service memcached start`

Comment: Please edit to include a few comments explaining these lines.

Comment: sudo apt-get install memcached will install the memcached service to your machine and with service memcached status command you can check the status of the service whether it is turn on or off later you could start and stop the service according to your convenience and might be you using memcached version for php5 that is why you facing error this will install according to your php version of your machine

Answer (score -1):

You need to first install memcached :

```
sudo apt install memcached
```

Then you need to start it :

```
sudo service memcached start
```

After that it will connect. I resolve it by above step in my case.

Comment: He stated that memcached is running (check by service memcached status).

Comment: I was also faced same issue but I was stop memcached and start again I resoved my issue. It seem to like port issue.